# Google Cloud App Engine gives 404 error when navigating to the link

Tags: google-app-engine

I am very new to App Engine so this might be something easy.

I am trying to upload a hello world Spring application to App Engine Flexible. The Spring application has 1 endpoint ("/") which returns the string "Hello world". I have used the Google App Engine plugin in Intellij to upload my application and the upload appears to go fine, I can see it in the App Engine dashboard. When I test the application locally by visiting localhost:8080, the text "Hello world" is displayed as expected.

The issue I am having is that when I click on the version within the App Engine dashboard, it takes me to a 404 error screen (see below) rather than displaying "Hello world".

> "404. That's an error. The requested URL was not found on this server.
> That's all we know.

[image]

I have also noted when I upload the the application, the traffic allocation is set to 0% and when I try to change the traffic allocation to 100% on the latest version I get another error which says "The traffic splitting settings cannot be saved."

My app.yaml file looks like this:

```
runtime: java
env: flex
service: spring-service

runtime_config: # Optional
  jdk: openjdk8

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    script: this field is required, but ignored

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your `app.yaml`:

```
service: spring-service
```

That should fix the problem.  You may want to read the documentation to understand what a `service` is with GAE.

Comment: Cheers for the reply, Yeah this did help. But I realised that I was being a bit of a noob. The  initial problem was caused because the app actually failed to deploy due to another reason. I was mistaking the fact that a version showed up in the dashboard as it being deployed.