# Custom domains / catch all hostnames on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, cloudflare

I'm trying to configure my Google App Engine instance with [Cloudflare for Saas](https://www.cloudflare.com/saas/), and more precisely Cloudflare's [SSL for SaaS](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/ssl-for-saas/) offering. The objective being that I can provide to my customer a "custom domain" (also known as "vanity domain"), such that they don't go to `dashboard.mywebsite.com`, but instead `app.customerwebsite.com`.

### Configuration part

To make sure that my App Engine instance is correctly serving content on `dashboard.mywebsite.com`, I've made the following:

#### On Google Cloud side:

- I've configured the custom domain `dashboard.mywebsite.com`.
- I've let Google manage the SSL configuration (no custom key/certificate)

[image: Google Cloud custom domain configuration]

- Here is my `app.yaml` configuration file:

```
runtime: nodejs14

env_variables:
  NODE_ENV: 'production'

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 10
  idle_timeout: 5m
```

#### On Cloudflare side:

- I've updated the DNS records so that `dashboard.mywebsite.com` is perfectly working
- I've configured the SSL on the **Full** mode (while I've tried with **Flexible** as well - both work)

[image: Cloudflare DNS zone]

I waited for a few hours and I confirm that `dashboard.mywebsite.com` resolves correctly and serves my content (from Google App Engine).

### Next, custom domains

According to [Cloudflare documentation](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/ssl-for-saas/getting-started/), I had to register the fallback origin (i.e. `dashboard.website.com`) and then configure a custom hostname (e.g. `app.customerwebsite.com`). Which I did.

[image: Custom Hostnames configuration in Cloudflare]

Now, according to [Cloudflare documentation again](https://developers.cloudflare.com/ssl/ssl-for-saas/getting-started/#step-5--have-customer-create-a-cname-record), my customer has to create a `CNAME` record. Which I did with a domain of mine:

```
app.customerwebsite.com CNAME dashboard.mycompany.com
```

### The issue

I waited a few hours again. Then, when I open `app.customerwebsite.com` in my browser, it shows a Google 404 error page instead of my dashboard. Which makes me think that Cloudflare successfully "redirects" the traffic to Google, but App Engine refuses to serve it. Probably because it doesn't know `app.customerwebsite.com`?

Any thoughts that would help?

Comment: can you share your app.yaml file, which might be helpful in troubleshooting the error.

Comment: I've updated the post with `app.yaml` details.

Comment: can you see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/q/70278759/15774176 is it helpful?

Comment: It might be linked, but wasn't helpful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, the issue is not related to Cloudflare, but App Engine. The problem with your configuration is that, when App Engine receives a request, based on the `Host` header, it forwards the request to the right instance.

App Engine lets you map any custom domains that has been previously validated by Google. But in your situation, that would mean you have to register each custom domain of your customers on your App Engine instance. That's too cumbersome (if even possible).

What you need to do instead is the following:

1. enable a static IP address with Google Cloud
2. change your DNS record from `dashboard CNAME ghs.googlehosted.com` to `dashboard A YOUR_IP_ADDRESS`
3. configure a Google Cloud Load Balancer to map requests received on that IP address to your App Engine instance.

Google's documentation has a great guide on how to [setup a load balancer with Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless). By changing a few settings it works great with App Engine. As an extra help, below is the configuration details of our load balancer that allows us to provide vanity domains / custom domains to our customers through Google Cloud:

[image: Google Cloud Load Balancer configuration details]

Again, the load balancer is here responsible to map all requests received by your IP address (no matter the `Host` header) straight to your App Engine instance.

As a best practice, it might be useful to push a `dispatch.yaml` file to your instance:

```
dispatch:
  - url: '*/*'
    service: default
```

Which tells App Engine to send all requests to the `default` service. It works a bit like a wildcard virtual hosts on an Apache server.

Comment: Do you have any idea how much this costs to run? Say, with no actual customers yet it looks expensive. I don't think there's any free tier for the load balancer.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it costs about $18 per month to run Google Cloud Load Balancing (1 rule) and $2.88/month to run the dedicated IP. Cloudflare is free up to 100 custom domains. So $20.88/month.